# not understanding compile errors in AIDL files

Tags: android, aidl

I'm taking my first foray into Android services and having trouble with compile errors in AIDL files.  I am using Eclipse (with Android Development Tools) and Android 4.1.  I have the following AIDL files:

***Weather.aidl***

```
package ws.hamacher.weatherservice.service;

parcelable ws.hamacher.weatherservice.dto.Weather;
```

In this file, I get "interface ws.hamacher.weatherservice.dto.Weather should be declared in a file called ws\hamacher\weatherservice\service\ws.aidl." on the parcelable line, but this refers to my Java class!

***IWeatherService.aidl***

```
package ws.hamacher.weatherservice.service;

import ws.hamacher.weatherservice.service.Weather;

interface IWeatherService {
    void addToWeatherService(in Weather weather);
    void deleteFromWeatherService(in Weather weather);
    List<Weather> getLocations();
}
```

Here again, the import statement gives a similar error "interface ws.hamacher.weatherservice.dto.Weather should be declared in a file called ws\hamacher\weatherservice\service\ws.aidl."  This should be referring to the first file above right?

Along with that, the method declarations all have errors, to the tune of "unknown type Weather".

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: what does the `import` line say in relation to the first aidl snippet? Why did you leave that vital bit out?

Comment: Thanks for the response.  Not quite understanding your question.  I've provided all the error messages and code.

Comment: `weather.aidl`, you have omitted something there? It should be wrapped in an **interface**

Comment: Like I said, this is a first time for me.  I am following an example in a book.  Please elaborate.  Thanks.

Comment: Look, show and paste the example? Please make your question 'to-point'. Simply quoting a bunch of unrelated code and let other guess your problem is not going to help the answerers

Comment: I have absolutely no idea what you want.  Look, the code is there and is not unrelated.  Perhaps you should take the time to read what I posted.  Unbelievable.

Comment: My comment was referring to the example in the book that you modified for yourself.... just sayin...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it.  My Weather.aidl had to be in the same directory as my parcelable Weather class.

Comment: I am getting the same error.. Can you please help me.. 
 Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you want to send custom object such as Weather class, you should creat a package:
ws.hamacher.weatherservice.dto

write :

Weather.java

in package: ws.hamacher.weatherservice.dto like this:

```
 public class Weather implements Parcelable {
....
}
```

Then, write Weather.aidl:

```
package ws.hamacher.weatherservice.dto;

parcelable Weather;
```

Please see [AndroidMusicPlayer](https://github.com/herbertdai/Android-Music-Player) and AndroidMusicPlayerClient for real code.

Comment: Thanks for your response.  I already created the Weather Java class as you said.

Comment: You can see the source code of AndroidMusicPlayer. Gald I could help.